# Finding element at index and not walking through all elements of list

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to implement a purely functional data structure (and realising how much I don't know).

I'm working through the exercises in "Functional Programming in Scala" https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala

And have implemented a data structure that appends, filters, maps and gets an item at an index:

```
package playground

import playground.List.{filter, getAtIndex, map}

import scala.annotation.tailrec
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List {

  def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = // Variadic function syntax
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

  def append[A](l: List[A] , item : A) : List[A] = {
    Cons(item , l)
  }

  def map[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] = {
    val buf = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[B]
    def mapCall(l: List[A]): Unit = l match {
      case Nil => ()
      case Cons(h,t) => buf += f(h); mapCall(t)
    }
    mapCall(l)
    List(buf.toList: _*)
  }

  def filter[A](l: List[A])(f: A => Boolean): List[A] = {
    val buf = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[A]
    def filterCall(l: List[A]): Unit = l match {
      case Nil => ()
      case Cons(h,t) => if (f(h)) buf += h; filterCall(t)
    }
    filterCall(l)
    List(buf.toList: _*)
  }

  def getAtIndex[A](l: List[A])(index : Int) : Option[A] = {
    var count = 0

    @tailrec
    def getAtIndexCall(l: List[A]): Option[A] = l match {
      case Nil => None
      case Cons(h,t) => if(count == index) {
        return Some(h)
      };
        count = count + 1
        println(count)
        getAtIndexCall(t)
    }
    getAtIndexCall(l)

  }

}

object FunctionTests extends App {

  val l : playground.List[Int] = List(1 ,2 ,3)
  println(List.append(l , 1))
  println(filter(l)(f => f > 1))
  println(map(l)(f =>f * 3))
  println(getAtIndex(l)(1))

}
```

The above code prints :

```
Cons(1,Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil))))
Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil))
Cons(3,Cons(6,Cons(9,Nil)))
1
Some(2)
```

I would prefer to implement `getAtIndex` such that it does not require searching from the beginning of the list until finding the element at the required index with performance O(N). Can an index be added to enable lookup with performance O(1)?

Scala Sequence allows this via `Seq(index)` , can point me in the direction of how to implement same/similar in above so that `getAtIndex` is more performant?

Update :

Map implemented using a `foldRight`

```
  def foldRight[A,B](as: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = // Utility functions
    as match {
      case Nil => z
      case Cons(x, xs) => f(x, foldRight(xs, z)(f))
    }
    
  def map[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] =
    foldRight(l, Nil:List[B])((h,t) => Cons(f(h),t))
```

Comment: First, what is even the point of implementing your own functional list if you are going to implement all methods using an imperative approach? The idea of this kind of exercises is to learn / understand functional approaches like **tail-recursion**. - Second, you can't, period. A single-linked list will always have an **O(N)** `apply` or `getByIndex`, that is the reason why the stdlib **List** behaves that way, not because the creators didn't care or were dumb, is simply not possible. That is why if you need that it is recommended to use other data structures like **Vector** or **ArraySeq**.

Comment: Note that, this is usually not a problem since most algorithms that are written on a functional style using a **List** are implemented in terms of _(tail)_ recursion. Thus, access by index is usually not required at all.

Comment: Not really, they are all using unnecessary mutable state like a **ListBuffer**. Again, I am not saying that the code is not wrong _per se_. I am just saying that the idea of implementing your own **List** is to get comfortable at writing tail-recursive immutable algorithms. Mutability is a tool that is useful in real-world code when performance matters or when the imperative approach to an algorithm is simpler than the immutable one. In your case it just makes everything slower since you iterate three times: 1) to build the buffer 2) the buffer to stdlib list 3) the stdlib list to your list.

Comment: Seq (sequence) is by definition sequential. If you need random access, use `IndexedSeq|`. Also, don't use `var`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez please see my question update - is this what you mean in terms of not using mutable state. In my update map function is implemented using a foldRight.

Comment: @blue-sky Yeah, that one is better :) - However, that `foldRight` is not stack safe it would be better to implement a tail-recursive `foldLeft` - anyway, this is becoming off-topic for SO or at least for this particular question since the answer, as I already said, is _"it is not possible"_.